# Understanding my trips to other cities

Tags: simcity-2013, simcity-buildit

When I visit other cities through the world exchange, there is a gray person symbol with a number in a red star right next to the city's name sign. What does that number represent?

Also, some cities give gifts for visiting, but this is inconsistent. What triggers these gifts?

Comment: If you ever return let me know if I answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is that users profile image. I believe if you link your game to Facebook that gives that image. The star is their player level. Just as you level up as do others and this just gives you an idea of their level.

The gifts trigger completely randomly. I have tested this and there is no pattern. You can leave and return and sometimes there will be a gift again, or if there wasn't one there could be second time.

Comment: I haven't linked my account so I'm not positive about setting the image, it might be a gravitar as well, but I've never attempted to change my own, only that I've seen peoples pictures on them in the past.

Comment: For some reason, the images don't work if you only connect using GameCenter.